# Print new line in the source-code with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, code-formatting

I have a simple function in jQuery that creates new elements in the DOM. the problem is  in the html source code, it append every element in the same line, and it's very bad to read.

```
function _loadNewElements(elements){
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
        var fixedElement = $('<img />')
        var position = elements[i].position;
        var cssMap = {
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': position.top + "px",
            'left': position.left + "px"
        };
        fixedElement.css(cssMap);
        fixedElement.addClass("fixedTag");
        fixedElement.attr('alt', elements[i].text);
        fixedElement.attr('src', "elements/" + elements[i].id + ".png");
        fixedElement.appendTo($('#board'));
        //i'd like to print something here like ("\n");

    }
}
```

I tried `document.write("\n")` but in this context it doesn't work.
Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this:

```
fixedElement.appendTo($('#board'));
```

I would cache the board selector outside your loop, like this:

```
var board = $('#board');
```

Then in your loop, replace the above with:

```
board.append(fixedElement).append('\n');
```

This will give you a new-line in the source and speed up your loop, since it's not looking for `#board` every time.  If you're using jQuery 1.4, you can use [`$(html, props)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) to shorten it all down to this:

```
function _loadNewElements(elements){
  var board = $('#board');
  for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    $('<img />', {
        css : { 'position': 'fixed',
              'top': elements[i].position.top + "px",
              'left': elements[i].position.left + "px" },
        'class': "fixedTag",
        'alt': elements[i].text,
        'src': "elements/" + elements[i].id + ".png"
    }).appendTo(board);
    board.append('\n'); //Add new-line for your source view
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `\r\n`? I believe that's the UTF-8 method of newline.